# Hodrick-Prescott derivation in lay terms

Tags: r, regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics

I am currently working with the Hodrick-Prescott filter.

I would like to understand the equation in lay terms.

Comment: Which equation in particular are you trying to understand?

Comment: Reference to particular terms doesn't help us. You need to display, or at least refer to, the equation as you thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this eq.?:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick%E2%80%93Prescott_filter

It quite directly says that first term penalizes for too much variation in cyclical component and other term tries to make trend term smooth by using penalty parameter lambda.

Some have noticed that HP-filter is related to Butterworth - filter in signal processing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter

You have one time series for which you postulate a model like this:

series=trend + cycle + seasonal + irregular

Problem is that you have only one series and four unknown components. Somehow these components must be extracted from the data and here you need some restrictions.

Low-pass filter is such that it completely removes variation from unwanted frequencies and leaves only series where variation from the wanted frequencies is kept.